# Record 2 channels (stereo) using AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudiosession

I have a video iOS app and would like it to record stereo sound for compatible devices. I notice the default camera app does record stereo sound from the built in microphones.

I'm using an AVAudioSession, and have 3 available built-in ports on my iPhone 11 - Front, Back and Bottom.

If I try to set the number of channels using session.setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels(2) it is failing with an error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50

I have tried setting this on all 3 available ports and get the same result on each. My question is whether it is possible and how does the default camera app achieve this?

This question which has already been asked, but as the previous question had no accepted answer I'm hoping it is ok -

Previous question - [How to use the stereo (2 channel) built in microphone in iPhone XS, inside AVAudioSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758113/how-to-use-the-stereo-2-channel-built-in-microphone-in-iphone-xs-inside-avaud)

Comment: The answer to the linked question seems correct. The default camera app is written by Apple, so it doesn't have the same rules. As the answer notes "And, the stereo microphone is not compatible with any third party app." Do you have some other question? Do you have reason to believe that answer is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier I have no reason to believe that it's incorrect but I couldn't find any reference to this anywhere else on the web and his answer wasn't well upvoted. I was wondering if there could be some other clever solution to this question such as combining the inputs of the 2 ports together to turn 2 mono inputs into stereo.

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to record stereo audio but it always just uses mono.